# AngularJS model binding to many text boxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following issue:

Let's assume I have a list of posts I will show using `ng-repeat`. After each post (plain text) I want to show a textbox and button. You can enter a comment in the textbox and when pressing the button you will add a comment to that specific post.

Like in here:

[image]

The problem I face is how can I build the model to the $scope in order to be unique for each specific post?

Now I have:

```
$scope.NewComment ={
    PostId: '',
    Comment: ''
};
```

If I bind the `NewComment.Comment` to the textarea then it will not work .. as each of the text-box will actually work for one single post.

Somehow I have to generate dynamic models for each of the post and comment which doesn't sound like a good option.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect candidate for a directive with an isolate scope :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using an angular directive with an isolate scope. This provides a separate scope for each instance of the directive that is created.

The usage of the directive looks like this:

```
<comment-box ng-repeat="box in boxes" title="box.title" comment="box.comment">
```

The directive JavaScript:

```
app.directive('commentBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'CommentBox.html',
    scope: {
      title: '=',
      comment: '='
    }
  }
});
```

The template html:

```
<div>
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="comment"/>
  <button data-ng-click="displayComment()">Post</button>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4Nw5jpJwH2q3kaIdwNYN?p=preview

You can pass through whatever you want into the isolate scope (including post id, etc.) but this should be a good starting point.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass through the specific comment in your `post()` function, something like this (in sudo-jade syntax...) may work, but I'm not sure if I understand what you are going for.

```
div(ng-repeat = "post in post")
   {{post.title}}
   input(type="text", ng-model="post.commentText")
   button(ng-click = "postComment(post)")
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.postComment = function (post) {
   console.log(post)
   newComment = {post_id:post.id, test:post.commentText}
}
```